# Dateformat in Jqgrid not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to search on the date field and I used the below code for the search datepicker, I need the date to be displayed as dd-M-yy format but in the search it shows as ddMyy omitting the '-' in between. Can you please suggest me the

```
DateSearch = function (elem) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                autoSize: true,
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showWeek: true,
                showButtonPanel: true
            })
        }, 100);
    }
```

[current appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs4k1.jpg)

Any help in this regards will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's important that you provide *more full information* about your problem. How looks like the input data for the column? How `colModel` is defined for the column? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: Hi @Oleg, Thank you for the reply ! I am using the JqGrid version - 4.4.3 .. the colModel defined is {
   name : 'startDT',
   index : 'startDT',
   width : 100,
   align: 'center',
   formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat:'d-M-Y', newformat: 'd-M-Y' },
   datefmt: 'd-M-Y',
            searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'], dataInit: DateSearch }
    } with the jqGrid property as below pager : '#pager',
  rowNum : 20,
  rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
  sortname : 'invid',
  sortorder : 'desc',
  viewrecords : true,
  gridview : true,
  caption : 'Data Load Report',
  }